# Quick way to check if the pandas series contains a negative value

Tags: python, pandas, series, negative-number, booleanquery

What is the quickest way to check if the given pandas series contains a negative value.

For example, for the series `s` below the answer is `True`.

```
s = pd.Series([1,5,3,-1,7])

0    1
1    5
2    3
3   -1
4    7
dtype: int64
```

Comment: `(s<0).sum()>0` ?

Comment: Even shorter - `(s<0).any()`

Comment: Even shorter - `any(s<0)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `any`

```
>>> s = pd.Series([1,5,3,-1,7])
>>> any(s<0)
True
```

Comment: Of all the answers, this is the fastest.

Comment: @MohitMotwani that depends on the size of the series and the index of the item less than zero.

Comment: @VanPeer In that case, is there a universal fastest answer to this?

Comment: Plus where would this method be slower compared to the other methods mentioned?

Comment: nice one. For those who are curious: have checked the runtime; `%timeit s.lt(0).any()` results in `72.8 µs ± 2.24 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)`; and `%timeit any(s<0)` results in `50.4 µs ± 1.65 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)`. (This may be faster on more modern systems, but only as an indication)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Series.lt` :

```
s = pd.Series([1,5,3,-1,7])
s.lt(0).any()
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: `lt` stands for 'less than'

Answer (score 0):

Use any function:

```
>>>s = pd.Series([1,5,3,-1,7])
>>>any(x < 0 for x in s)
True
>>>s = pd.Series([1,5,3,0,7])
>>>any(x < 0 for x in s)
False
```